# supervisorctl ERROR (abnormal termination)

Tags: supervisord

When I run `sudo supervisorctl start stage` then I get `ERROR (abnormal termination)`. Will you please take look?

Here is my file `/etc/supervisord.conf`. Am i missing something? thanks

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/tmp/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)
[supervisord]
logfile=/tmp/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
logfile_maxbytes=50MB       ; (max main logfile bytes b4 rotation;default 50MB)
logfile_backups=10          ; (num of main logfile rotation backups;default 10)
loglevel=info               ; (log level;default info; others: debug,warn,trace)
pidfile=/tmp/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
nodaemon=false              ; (start in foreground if true;default false)
minfds=1024                 ; (min. avail startup file descriptors;default 1024)
minprocs=200                ; (min. avail process descriptors;default 200)

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket

[program:stage]
command=/home/me/envs/project/bin/python /home/me/webapps/project/manage.py run_gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:8002 --log-file=/tmp/stage_gunicorn.log
directory=/home/me/webapps/project/
user=www-data
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/tmp/stage_supervisord.log
redirect_stderr=true
```

Comment: What happens when you run `/home/me/envs/project/bin/python /home/me/webapps/project/manage.py run_gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:8002 --log-file=/tmp/stage_gunicorn.log` in directory `/home/me/webapps/project/` as user `www-data`? Supervisord is just telling you that that program is not working as expected, you'll need to find out why.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I meet the same problem as yours. As Martijn Pieters saying, it doesn't mean that something goes wrong with your supervisorctl. It just tells you that the program didn't work. You can find some error details in the log.

Comment: You can also use `supervisorctl tail <APP_NAME>` to easily access the log.

Comment: Thanks - this was helpful! In my case supervisor was 'stuck' calling an invalid command, which kept erroring in the program, so I had to restart supervisor to pick up the new configuration (reload/add still failed until I did that).

Answer (score 17):

It indicated error so find it using below command :

```
supervisorctl tail <APP_NAME>
```

Answer (score 1):

This error is occurring due to the underlying stage application is not running properly. To fix the error, you can simply go to your console and run the command that you are passing. In your case:

It is

```
    /home/me/envs/project/bin/python /home/me/webapps/project/manage.py run_gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:8002 --log-file=/tmp/stage_gunicorn.log
```

It will show you the error that need to be fixed

Answer (score 0):

It means that your APP is wrong.
Go and check [program:stage] section, path or something is not c

Answer (score 0):

Just edit the log level to `trace` then restart supervisord and see what happened from the supervisor log.

```
[supervisord]
loglevel=trace
```

`sudo systemctl restart supervisord.service`

`tail -f /path/to/supervisord.log`

When the problem has been resolved, modify the loglevel to info.